# Primefaces multiple dynamic content panels to be displayed

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to do a kind of simple customizable news view page into my web application, like [Google's one](https://news.google.es/) but much simpler, with frames. Each frame object simply has his title and an url to be added as its content.

I'm using **JSF and primefaces**, both on their newest versions. So my backing bean, which is `@ViewScoped`, has access to the logged user, which is stored in a `@SessionScoped` bean, and that user has his corresponding frames loaded.

Problem comes when I try to iterate it over the `@ViewScoped` bean, because the only way I find to do it is with a `c:forEach` tag. That's the way I do:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">
<h:form>
    <p:panel header="Noticias">
        <h:panelGrid columns="#{fn:length(navegableHomeManager._UserFrames)}"
            width="100%">
            <c:forEach var="frame" items="#{navegableHomeManager._UserFrames}">
                <p:column>
                    <p:panel header="#{frame._Name}" closable="true"
                        style="width:95%;height:500px;" id="#{frame._Name}">
                        <p:ajax event="close"
                            listener="#{navegableHomeManager.actionFrameClosed}" />
                        <ui:include src="#{frame._Path}" />
                    </p:panel>
                </p:column>
            </c:forEach>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

That iteration obviusly does not work with `navegableHomeManager` bean because it is `@ViewScoped`. So the bean will be rebuilt in each of the iterations. The solution I've reached uses another `@SessionScoped` bean between the `navegableHomeManager` and the `loggedBean`, so that way the frames are stored there and I can have access to them properly into the iteration. That's working with the code above.

However I don't think it should be compulsory to use a `@SessionScoped` bean (creating an specific bean for every single case) every time I want to iterate in that way. **That's why I have tried using components to avoid the iteration.**

```
<p:dataGrid columns="#{fn:length(navegableHomeManager._UserFrames)}"
            value="#{navegableHomeManager._UserFrames}" var="frame">
    <p:column>
        <p:panel header="#{frame._Name}" closable="true"
                    style="width:95%;height:500px;">
            <p:ajax event="close"
                        listener="#{navegableHomeManager.actionFrameClosed}" />
            <ui:include src="#{frame._Path}" />
        </p:panel>
    </p:column>
</p:dataGrid>
```

It doesn't work neither when the bean is `@ViewScoped` or `@SessionScoped`, because even the frames properties are set, the `ui:include` tag has already been built with no destination path, so I can't render the destination path dinamically. I think that, as `ui:include` is being applied at the same time as `c:forEach`, using a `c:forEach` tag is really the only way to go through this.

Pool your ideas.

**UPDATE**

Here I post more *xhtml* code to help in the understanding of the context. The new's page is integrated into a template. That's the page which is targeted (*/system/home/index.xhtml*):

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
template="/templates/general_template.xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<ui:define name="metadata">
    <f:event type="preRenderView"
        listener="#{navegableHomeManager.initialize}" />
</ui:define>

<ui:define name="general_content">
    <ui:include src="/system/home/home_view.xhtml" />
</ui:define>
```

And that's the way I also tried to do it, but not making the `c:forEach` tag to work:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FULL_STATE_SAVING_VIEW_IDS</param-name>
    <param-value>/system/home/index.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And that's the backing bean header:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
@URLMapping(id = "home", pattern = "/home", viewId = "/system/home/index.xhtml")
public class NavegableHomeManager extends SystemNavegable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6239319842919211716L;

@ManagedProperty(value = "#{loggedBean}")
private LoggedBean _LoggedBean;

//More stuff
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stick to `<c:forEach>`. It does the job you're looking for. The `<ui:include>` runs during view build time, so the iteration tag should also run during view build time.

As to the `@ViewScoped` bean problem, you've 2 options:

1. Turn off partial state saving for the particular view:

   ```
   <context-param>
       <param-name>javax.faces.FULL_STATE_SAVING_VIEW_IDS</param-name>
       <param-value>/news.xhtml</param-value>
   </context-param>
   ```
2. Change it to a `@RequestScoped` bean and use `<f:param>` and `@ManagedProperty` to maintain state across postbacks by request parameters.

There would be a third option if JSF 2.2 is available: just upgrade to JSF 2.2. They've fixed the chicken-egg problem in view scoped beans and partial state saving.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For some reason, the `context-param` based solution is not working. `navegableHomeManager` is recovering now the frames directly from the `loggedBean`, but the `forEach` tag is not doing the iteration even `#{fn:length(navegableHomeManager._UserFrames)}` returns `1`. The bean is only built when I access the page, which is correct. I also can't upgrade to JSF 2.2 since there are no stable releases and I can't trust on it 100%.

Comment: As to context param, apparently you specified the wrong view ID (note: a view ID is not an URL, it's the context-relative path to the physical file, so even if you mapped your JSF thing on `*.jsf`, you should still use `.xhtml` in view ID). As to remainder, sorry it's hard to understand the problem based on the information provided so far.

Comment: I have updated the question adding more of my code BalusC. Hope it will help.

Comment: The `preRenderView` event doesn't run during view build time. Use postconstruct.