# Slowness with with multiple ui:includes

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, mojarra

We have a page in which the main content area is controlled by `ui:includes`, basically we have a `h:panelGroup` with a `rendered` condition and the `ui:include` inside of it.

Like this:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.page.id eq bean.page1ID}">
        <ui:include src="page.xhtml"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

We have about 10 of those. Each page is pretty complex, having a few beans of their own. The reason we are doing the rendered trick instead of a dynamic `ui:include` is because there is a bug in which the `@ViewScoped` beans used outside the `ui:include` get re-instantiated inside the `ui:include` thus causing all sorts of issues.

Any time we perform some action it takes several seconds (7 to 15 usually) for the action to be performed. For example when we change the `bean.page` property and request a render. Even when we do something simple like saving a value which doesn't involve hardly anything else it is really slow. If I remove all the `h:panelGroups` and `ui:includes` except for one then the site is really fast (1 to 2 second response). As far as I can tell all the pages in the `ui:includes` and the beans they use are getting instantiated.

What can we do to speed this up? we are using mojarra 2.1.13 on resin 4.0.32 and primefaces 3.5.

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you to use [custom facelet tags](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-tags-in-jsf-2-0/) instead of `<ui:include>` ones. Including whole pages with JSF logic can carry you problems since they're included when page is built, and not when it's rendered. [Look at the problem I experienced with a `@ViewScoped` bean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518133/primefaces-multiple-dynamic-content-panels-to-be-displayed).

Comment: I had that same problem which is why I went with the `h:panelGroup` and `rendered` instead of having a dynamic `ui:include`. I'll have to look into the custom facelet tag.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any custom context parameters? Wrong values there can significantly influence the performance.

You could try to disable the facelets refresh in your `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
  <param-value>-1</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Setting this value to -1 disables the internal check for view declaration changes. This means that you cannot reload your xhtml pages without a redeploy but it also means higher performance.

Alternatively, you could also try to set the project stage to `Production` (this should include the other parameter). This disables lots of additional checks and stuff for development:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Those two settings should **always** be used in a productive environment.