# JSF - create page on the fly

Tags: jsf

I'm looking for a genial idea on how to create a jsf page on the fly based on a given template.

Here's the requirements:

The user has several templates between which he chooses one.
The chosen template is displayed and for each placeholder in the template the user can select what he wants to display in the given placeholder. It can be a table, a chart etc...
This configuration is saved in the database and displayed to the user when he logs in.

Now building a template is easy:

```
    <div class="top-left" >
         <ui:insert name="top-left"/>
     </div>
    <div class="top-right" >
        <ui:insert name="top-right"/>
    </div>
```

The problems start when I try to do this:

```
<ui:decorate template="#{myBean.template}.xhtml" >
    <ui:repeat value="#{myBean.placeholders}" var="placeholder" >
        <ui:define name="#{placeholder}">    //FaceletException: name Must be Literal
            //display here the chosen component (chart, table ect...)
        </ui:define>
    </ui:repeat>
</ui:decorate>
```

Any ideas are much appreciated!

**Edit:**
Seems like I'll have to give up the ui:define with dynamic name 'cause although in the [specs](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/pdldocs/facelets/ui/define.html) it can be specified as a value expression in the [implementation](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-923) of

- Mojarra 2.x
- MyFaces 2.x
- Facelets 1.x

it is expected to be a literal.

Comment: You are looking for HTML or JSF components inside your _display here the chosen component_ ?

Answer (score 1):

You must differ between tag handlers and components in JSF. While [tag handlers execute when view is built, components do when page is being rendered](https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat). Basically, mixing both of them when building a view carelessly can carry you on problems.

Basically, `ui:decorate` and `ui:define` tags run while your view is being built. `ui:repeat` tag has not been rendered, so it means your iteration will not be properly executed. You must stick to `c:forEach` in this case. Take a look to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518133/primefaces-multiple-dynamic-content-panels-to-be-displayed).

Appart from that, I strongly believe that JSF is not the most appropiate tool for the job you want to achieve, as it has strong limitations for what you're looking for.

Comment: You're right, thanks for the tip. Can you suggest a more appropriate tool?

Comment: I get the same error also with c:forEach: javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: <ui:define name="#{placeholder}"> Must be Literal